# Error message in Access form with both manual and calculated data entries

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, input

my Access 2010 form is used to input data. Some fields manually (type in or choice from a dropdownlist), some other fields get precalculated values depending on the already input data. Additional code controls enabling or disabling input fields dependent from the input data (ensuring data consistency).

**My problem**: When I choose a value (from a dropdownlist) in a field then switch to the next field (any method: mouse/tab/code) and try to enter a value, I get an [erroneous] error message that "another user" (obviously my own VBA code) has modified this record and saved it before my own changes were saved. But everything is OK and the second trial to input data is successful.

I tried Me.Recalc and Me.Refresh at different positions in the code without eliminating this nasty error. How can I tell Access 2010 to save my input data in a field before starting running the code [MyPreviousField_AfterUpdate()] ?

Comment: docmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord

Answer (score 0):

docmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord unfortunately does not work at all, as my problemativ fields are unbound. It's the mix of related bound and unbound fields which Access does not handle as one could expect. Disabling error messages or record lock, or even Me.Undo or Me.MyField1.Undo do not work at all either.

However, I now found a work-around myself. Note that simply setting the focus on other field may sometimes push Access to save the values then avoiding the erroneous error message, but this often fails. Following code works not always either but is practicable for only few changes in the form:

```
Dim MyFieldVal1 As Variant, MyFieldVal2 As Variant    ', … [all unbound fields]
Private Sub MyField1_Change()
    …
    If Not IsNull(Me![MyField1]) Then MyFieldVal1 = Me![MyField1]
    If Not IsNull(Me![MyField2]) Then MyFieldVal1 = Me![MyField2]
    …      ' same for all unbound fields on the form
    Call SaveAllValues(Me.Name, Me.CurrentRecord)
    …
    …    ' here all code to change any field but WITHOUT Me.Refresh
    …
    Me![MyField1] = MyFieldVal1
    Me![MyField2] = MyFieldVal2
    …      ' same for all unbound fields on the form
    Me.Refresh
End Sub
'===================================================
Sub SaveAllValues(ByVal FormName, ByVal CurRec)
    DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, FormName, acFirst
    DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, FormName, acGoTo, CurRec
End Sub
```

The whole procedure is tedious as above code must be implemented for each unbound field: MyField2_Change() etc. etc.

It worked correctly for quite a while, but after minor other changes at other places in the code, the errors appears reproducibly again ! Obviously the result depends on Access' last code compilation, sometimes leading to other erratic problems. Probably the module is corrupt (database repair does not correct anything). I have to live with the erroneous error or to begin designing a new form from scratch again…

Maybe it is just impossible to mix bound and unbound fields on the same form, one has no other way than to use subforms for the bound data ?

Answer (score 0):

FINAL REPORT :  It's just yet another MS Access bug !

I redesigned my form to a main form with a number of database fields and a subform with 3 unbound fields. This changes of course the navigation sequence between fields. The same error as previously described occurs each time one switches from an unbound field to another unbound field on the subform, then to a database field on the main form.

The problem is resolved by adding following lines at the end of each unbound field change procedure:

```
Private Sub MyUnboundField1_Change()
    …
    Me.Refresh
    Me.Parent.Requery
End Sub
```